# How would I detect collision in tile-based movement?

Tags: python, pygame

I recently started programming in Python and the Pygame module. I'm trying to make a game where the player moves block-by-block, however I don't know where to start in collision detection.

For example, the player should be able to move in the grass, but would not be able to enter the water. This is what I have so far:

```
import pygame as pg, sys

# Frames
clock = pg.time.Clock()

# Colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

# Tile declarations
GRASS = 0
WATER = 1

# Tile colors
colors = {
    GRASS: GREEN,
    WATER: BLUE
}

# Tile dimensions
tileWidth = 50
tileHeight = 50

# Map
tileSet = [
    [GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS],
    [GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS],
    [GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, WATER, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS],
    [GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, WATER, WATER, WATER, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS],
    [GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, WATER, WATER, WATER, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS],
    [GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, WATER, WATER, WATER, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS],
    [GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, WATER, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS],
    [GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS],
    [GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS]
]

# Map dimensions
mapWidth = 12
mapHeight = 9

# Screen dimensions
screenWidth = tileWidth * mapWidth
screenHeight = tileHeight * mapHeight

# Set up display
pg.init()
win = pg.display.set_mode((screenWidth, screenHeight))


class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y, color):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pg.Surface([tileWidth, tileHeight])
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y


def map_gen():
    for row in range(mapHeight):
        for elementInRow in range(mapWidth):
            pg.draw.rect(win, colors[tileSet[row][elementInRow]], [elementInRow * tileWidth, row * tileHeight, tileWidth, tileHeight])


def main():
    sprite_list = pg.sprite.Group()
    player = Player(0, 0, RED)
    sprite_list.add(player)
    # Game loop variable
    running = True
    while running:
        # Inputs
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                running = False
            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_w:
                    player.rect.y -= tileHeight
                if event.key == pg.K_a:
                    player.rect.x -= tileWidth
                if event.key == pg.K_s:
                    player.rect.y += tileHeight
                if event.key == pg.K_d:
                    player.rect.x += tileWidth
        # Map
        map_gen()
        sprite_list.update()
        sprite_list.draw(win)
        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the map, you can store the character position as `x, y` coordinates, and check if the tile you want to move to is of the specify tiype:

For example:

```
# Map
tileSet = [
    [GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS],
    [GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS],
    [GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, WATER, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS],
    [GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, WATER, WATER, WATER, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS],
    [GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, WATER, WATER, WATER, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS],
    [GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, WATER, WATER, WATER, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS],
    [GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, WATER, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS],
    [GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS],
    [GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS, GRASS]]

player_pos = [5, 5]

...
            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_w:
                    if tileSet[player_pos[1]+1][player_pos[0]] != WATER:
                        player_pos[1] += 1
                        player.rect.y -= tileHeight
...
```

Take care with the [coordinates system](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/10098/starting-off-with-coordinate-systems)